# Integrating Apache kafka with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, apache-kafka

I created a Topic 'sample' in apache kafka and run the producer, published messages into it. I run consumer in other terminal able to see the published messages. now I want to display messgaes in Grid using Angularjs. Is there way to consume messages and display as table ?

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS is a client side technology, whereas Kafka is a server side.

One way you can achieve this is by creating a kafka consumer, with which will send result to websockets. And this socket is consumed by angular.

Comment: can you please give example how to do that

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Kafka clients page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients#Clients-Node.js) there's a node.js client. I haven't used it myself, but the [project's github repo](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/) seems to be active.